# Visual Studio 2019 Publish removes write permission from folder

Tags: visual-studio, security, publish, webdeploy

I have a folder to which my file upload control writes files. When I publish the project, the folder is deleted and recreated. This is expected, as I am using the *Folder* (`FileSystem`) publishing method with the *Delete Existing Files* (`DeleteExistingFiles`) flag. In the process, however, the write permission on my folder are removed, thus breaking my upload process.

I've already tried adding the following into my `.csproj` file, but it doesn't work for me:

```xml
<IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination>False</IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination>
```

Part of my challenge here is that I can't find any documentation regarding this for Visual Studio 2019, only older versions.